# Device Position vs Simulator Position

Tags: ios

I have written code for the side bar. It displays properly on the simulator, but not on the actual device. I could not able to figure that out? I defined my storyboard with landscape layout. Device is running 7.0 but simulator 8.1.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     [sideBarLeft insertMenuButtonOnView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window atPosition:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width-980,0) atSite:@"Left"];

}
```

Simulator:

[image]
Device

[image]

Comment: what version of iOS are you running on, and where in the view lifecycle are you calling `insertMenuButtonOnView:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In earlier versions of iOS (7 and below), `UIWindow` coordinate systems do not rotate. 
When attempting to add a subview to a window, it was common practice to apply a transform based on current device orientation. (similar to the accepted answer here: [iPhone - UIWindow rotating depending on current orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697605/iphone-uiwindow-rotating-depending-on-current-orientation))

For iOS 8 and above, UIWindow coordinate systems DO rotate, so applying this transform is no longer necessary. If your app targets ONLY iOS 8+ you should not have to change your code, if you are targeting anything older than that, you'll need to put in handling similar to the answer I linked above.