# Newly created UIWindow is sideways when app is opened on landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwindow

I have an iPad application in which I create a new `UIWindow` at the beginning of the app and show it while I do some resource synchronization. When the app is launched while the iPad is on portrait orientation, everything's fine. However, when on landscape orientation, the newly created `UIWindow's` size seems fine but it appears sideways and it's coordinates seem all weird. Here are the screenshots for both portrait and landscape orientations:

[image]

[image]

The landscape one is obtained by rotating to right once.

The piece of code where I create and show the `UIWindow` is as follows:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
self.progressWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];
self.progressWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
self.progressWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;

/* some other code to create the subviews */

[self.progressWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This problem only occurs on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, newly created UIWindow's do not rotate automatically when the orientation changes. I don't know whether this is new to iOS 8 or if it is a bug, but I was able to overcome the problem with the following piece of code:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
self.progressWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];
self.progressWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
self.progressWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;

/* some other code to create the subviews */

[self handleOrientationChange];
[self.progressWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleOrientationChange) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Implementation for handleOrientationChange is as follows:

```
#define DegreesToRadians(degrees) (degrees * M_PI / 180)

- (void)handleOrientationChange
{
    if (self.progressWindow)
    {
        // rotate the UIWindow manually
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        [self.progressWindow setTransform:[self transformForOrientation:orientation]];

        // resize the UIWindow according to the new screen size
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeBounds)])
        {
            // iOS 8
            CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds;
            CGRect progressWindowFrame = self.progressWindow.frame;
            progressWindowFrame.origin.x = 0;
            progressWindowFrame.origin.y = 0;
            progressWindowFrame.size.width = screenRect.size.width / [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale;
            progressWindowFrame.size.height = screenRect.size.height / [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale;
            self.progressWindow.frame = progressWindowFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOs 7 or below
            CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
            CGRect progressWindowFrame = self.progressWindow.frame;
            progressWindowFrame.origin.x = 0;
            progressWindowFrame.origin.y = 0;
            progressWindowFrame.size.width = screenRect.size.width;
            progressWindowFrame.size.height = screenRect.size.height;
            self.progressWindow.frame = progressWindowFrame;
        }
    }
}

- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    switch (orientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DegreesToRadians(90));

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        default:
            return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
    }
}
```

I got the idea from the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697605/iphone-uiwindow-rotating-depending-on-current-orientation) question.

Answer (score 0):

> The shared application maintains a reference to the window through its
>   key- Window property:
>
> `let w = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow`
>
> That reference, however,
>   is slightly volatile, because the system can create temporary windows
>   and interpose them as the application’s key window.

try instead

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]
```

Comment: I am only using keyWindow to get its frame, so I don't think that is the problem.